# How to use regex to replace letters between HTML-tags in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace all letters "e" in a HTML site with é.
So I have to find all "e"´s between `<p>` and `</p>` and replace them - but nowhere else in the HTML-file.

I think I am close by using a regex:

```
e+(?=[^<p>]*?</p>)
```

but it doesn´t start right after the opening tag.

What did I wrong?

Comment: Use `e(?=[^<>]*</p>)`

Comment: How complex is your HTML document? In general, [HTML can't be parsed with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). What if you have an `<em>` or `<a href="...">` tag in your `<p>`? Good luck preventing these `e`s from being replaced. An HTML parser is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is mostly for regex educational purposes. Please use an HTML/XML parser to get manipulate text nodes in a DOM structure.**

The `e+(?=[^<p>]*?</p>)` regex matches 1 or more `e` chars that are followed with any 0+ chars other than `<`, `>` and `p`, as few as possible, up to the `</p>` substring. It means  you will match `e`s in `e 1 e 2 </p>`, but you won't match any `e` in `e x e p </p>`, see [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PPf4Wp/1).

You may fix the issue using

```
e(?=[^<>]*</p>)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PPf4Wp/2). Here, any single `e` is matched that is followed with any 0+ chars other than `<` and `>` and then `</p>`.

**However**, the regex above does not check if the `e` char is preceded with `<p>`. You may require that using

```
(?:\G(?!^)|<p(?:\s[^>]*)?>)[^<>]*?\Ke(?=[^<>]*</p>)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PPf4Wp/3)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|<p(?:\s[^>]*)?>)` - end of the previous match or `<p` followed with an optional sequence of a whitespace and any 0+ chars other than `>` and then `>`
- `[^<>]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`, as few as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `e` - an `e`
- `(?=[^<>]*</p>)` - there must be 0 or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then `</p>`.

This will work with multiline `p` tags. However, **it won't handle nested tags**.